# Show that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then $\sum f(\frac1n)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help with this problem:
*Let $f$ be a continous function over an interval that contains $0$. Let $a_n = f(\frac 1 n)$ (for n large enough).*

1. Show that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges.

I've already shown  that *if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges, then $f(0)=0$* and that *if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges, then $f'(0)=0$.*

How do I show this one?

Answer (score 1):

We can use comparison test based on the following fact
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{2x}=\frac{f''(0)}{2}
$$ where L'Hopital's rule is used in the first equation. Thus for all sufficiently large $n\ge N$,
$$
n^2|a_n| = n^2\left|f\left(\frac1n\right)\right|\le |f''(0)|
$$ hence
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}|a_n| \le \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} |a_n|+\sum_{n\ge N} \frac{|f''(0)|}{n^2}<\infty. 
$$ The series converges absolutely, which implies that the series converges.

Comment: Why did you compare it to $x^2$?

Comment: @davidllerenav It is a natural choice in view of the Taylor-Mclaurin expansion $f(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x +\frac{f''(0)}2 x^2 +\cdots \cong \frac{f''(0)}2 x^2$. Also, $2$ is the first exponent $r\in \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac1{n^r}<\infty$. (Thus we find that $\sum_{n\ge 1}f(1/n)\cong \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{f'(0)}{n}$ does not converge if $f'(0)\ne 0$.)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Can't I also do it by the limit comparison? Because I already proved that if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges then $f'(0)=0$. I did it by using the derivative definition and supposing that $f'(0)$ isn't 0, ending up with $\lim_n\to\infty nf(\frac 1 n)=t$. Then by the limit comparison test, I reached a contradiction, thus $f'(0)=0$. Can't I do it that way instead?

Comment: @davidllerenav Yes, you can also do it by limit comparison test. Indeed, what I wrote in my answer can be viewed as a logic behind applying limit comparison test.

Comment: So if I just write the same thing but with $f''(0)$ and show that $f''(0)=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ must converge?

Comment: @davidllerenav Yes, it's right.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I still needed to prove that the series converges. Since I only know that the derivatives at 0 are 0 and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ and that means that it either converges or diverges. But I don't have to, right?

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's Formula with remainder $|f(x)| \leq  cx^{2}$ for some constant $C$ for $x$ in a neighborhoodod $0$. Hence $\sum f(\frac 1 n)$ is dominated by a constant times $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: Why is the remainder $cx^2$? Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: $\frac {f'(x)|} {|x|}=\frac {|f'(x)-f'(0)|} {|x|}  \to f''(0)$. From this it follows that $|f'(x)| <(1+|f''(0)|) |x|$ if $|x|$ is sufficiently small. Now $|f(x))=|f(x)-f(0)|=|x||f'\zeta)|$ for some $\zeta$ between $0$ and $x$. Is it clear now that $|f(x)| \leq Mx^{2}$ for some $M$, for $|x|$ is sufficiently small?

Answer (score 0):

As $f''(0)$ exists, $f'(0)$ is can be linearly approximated:
$$ f'(h) = m\cdot h+ r(h)$$

With some function $r$ with $\frac {r(h)} h\to 0$ for $h\to 0 $. Therefore we can find an interval $U:=[-a,a]$ so that $ r(h) \le m\cdot h$, and by that:
$$x\in U\implies f'(x) \le 2 m\cdot x
$$

From this follows $f(x) \le mx^2$ per integration for $x\in U$, and thus the sum converges
(as for some $N$ the tail of the sum, $\sum_{i=N}^\infty f(1/i)$, is completely in $U$ for all $i$ it assumes, and we know that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac 1 {x^2}$ converges).